# what does ++array[str[i]]; does?

Tags: c++, arrays

I found a program to print out the most frequent character in an array of char.
Here is the code.

```
void main()
{

    int array[255] = {0}; // initialize all elements to 0

    char str[] = "thequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydog";

    int i, max, index;

    for(i = 0; str[i] != 0; i++)
    {
        ++array[str[i]];
    }

    // then find the most used charater ...
}
```

I don't really understand what `++array[str[i]];`does.

We initialized the array as `int array[255]` but it still accepts the index as `str[i]` which I believe is **char type**.

Is it because `str[i]` automatically turn into ASCII ?  And what `++` preceding the command does ?

Comment: They are converted to their ASCII.

Comment: ++ increments the value

Comment: And about that `++` it's called pre-increment.

Comment: That should ideally split the string into characters and store in the array. Like a dictionary with keys as ASCII value of characters and values as the number of occurences.

Comment: `array['a']` **is** `array[97]`. Check the ascii table

Comment: Just fyi, *not* casting that index to `unsigned char` is a recipe for disaster. Further, this is not using a table guaranteed to hold enough slots to cover the domain. i.e. `1 << CHAR_BIT` in width. It will "work" (term used loosely) for your input string presented here. It is *not* an end-all general solution to char counting.

Comment: @WhozCraig I referenced your input in my answer. Do you mind if I copy? Keeping crediting you of course.

Comment: @Yunnosch makes no difference to me.

Comment: Note that it should be `int array[256]` because 255 is a valid char (assuming that it is an unsigned type in your environment).

Answer (score 1):

In this code

```
++array[str[i]];
```

`i` walks the length of `str` (because of the setup of the loop we are inside...).

For each character inside `str`, the expression `str[i]` gets the value of that character. I use "value" instead of "character", because it later is treated as an integer index.

With that value the expression `array[str[i]]` accesses one of the entries in the array. Each entry in that array corresponds to one possible ASCII "character".

The `++` increments the value in the array. I.e. it counts the number of occurrences of e.g. 'a'.

In total, the code makes a histogram of ASCII character frequency inside `str`.

Note however the important warning by WhozCraig, in case you intend to use this. You have to match the assumptions the code makes (copied with permission, for completeness):

> Just fyi, not casting that index to unsigned char is a recipe for disaster. Further, this is not using a table guaranteed to hold enough slots to cover the domain. i.e. 1 << CHAR_BIT in width. It will "work" (term used loosely) for your input string presented here. It is not an end-all general solution to char counting.

Answer (score 0):

First, the initialization of the array to size `255` is because the `ascii` values of the characters are in this range. so for example when you call `str[i]=a` it translate to the value `97` which is a part of the `array`. you could see the values in the following `ascii` table, http://www.asciitable.com

Second, the operator `++array[str[i]];` is called *pre-increment* which is just adds `1` to the value in the array, in the following case you could use the *post-increment* and you will get the same result, `array[str[i]]++`;

reference to read about the *post/pre increment*: 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pre-increment-and-post-increment-in-c/